# Spring SpEL and BigDecimal expressions

Tags: spring-el

We're using Spring Expression Language (v3.1.2) to validate Object values in a map. The two test cases below outline a scenario where we are asserting the value of a BigDecimal object. The first case passes but the second test fails. I think the way we have defined the expression is correction, but is suspect the implementation is not correctly casting the object value.

```
@Test
public void testBigDecimalValueLess() { 

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("premiums",new BigDecimal("400000.000000"));

    StandardEvaluationContext stdContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    stdContext.setVariables(map);

    // Set expression
    String ruleExpression = "#premiums>=new java.math.BigDecimal('500000')";
    // Evaluate the SpEL expression
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(ruleExpression);
    Boolean returnValue = expression.getValue(stdContext,Boolean.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE,returnValue);
}

@Test
public void testBigDecimalValueGreater() { 

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("premiums",new BigDecimal("119000000000.000000"));

    StandardEvaluationContext stdContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    stdContext.setVariables(map);

    // Set expression
    String ruleExpression = "#premiums>=new java.math.BigDecimal('500000')";
    // Evaluate the SpEL expression
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(ruleExpression);
    Boolean returnValue = expression.getValue(stdContext,Boolean.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE,returnValue);
}
```

Is there any recommended way to we can achive this on the currect version. Can i pass extra information
to the StandardEvaluationContext object?

EDIT 1

I written this test to show how the BigDecimal values are cast to 'int' and 'long'

```
@Test
public void bigDecimalIntValue(){
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1000").intValue());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("100000").intValue());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10000000").intValue());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1000000000").intValue());
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("100000000000").intValue()); --> 1215752192
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("100000000000").longValue()); --> 100000000000
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("713027290000.000000").intValue()); --> 62718864
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("713027290000.000000").longValue()); --> 713027290000
}
```

I suspect i just need to ensure my expression casts both numbers to a Long before the operation is evaluated.

Comment: Passes on SF 4.0 and 4.1. Show, please, the exception on the matter

Comment: I don't get an exception, it seems under the hood the 'new BigDecimal("119000000000.000000")' value is cast to a number, which then has 'intValue()' called apon it. The intValue() returns value of '-1259084288'. If divide the BigDecimal value by 100,000 the value drops into the valid range of an int, so the expression then passes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `compareTo(BigDecimal val)` method of BigDecimal class. For details of this method, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29 and change your expression to something like this:

```
String ruleExpression = "#premiums.compareTo(new java.math.BigDecimal('500000')) >= 0";
```

Comment: I get EL1002E: Constructor call: no suitable constructor found on type java.math.BigDecimal